# How to add an edittext in the middle of the toolbar?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext, toolbar

I want to add an edit text directly to the toolbar. The edittext is always shown below or above the toolbar. What can I do?

I tried to put the edit text in app_bar_nav.xml, but that doesnt help with the position of it. I also tried an include statement and changing the layout type to linear layout... also without a good result.

app_bar_nav.xml

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".NavActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/myEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack"
        android:hint="Adresse" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" />

<include layout="@layout/content_nav" />
```

activity_nav.xml

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">


<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_nav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_nav"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_nav_drawer" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Edit text inside Toolbar it self, please try below code

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/myEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack"
        android:hint="Adresse" />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: great,please mark this answer as right answer may be someone else facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use search as a menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:title="Search"/>
</menu>
```

and access it in Activity/ Fragment

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
   menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);
   MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
   SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
   SearchView searchView = null;
   if (searchItem != null) {
    searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
   }
   if (searchView != null){
       searchView.setSearchableInfo( searchManager.getSearchableInfo(MainActivity.this.getComponentName()));
   }
   return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use SearchView instead of EditText.

Add this code to the xml

```
<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/simpleSearchView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:queryHint="Search View"
    android:background="#f00"
    android:padding="40dp"/>
```

Here's [how](https://abhiandroid.com/ui/searchview)